# How to override a css important rule in a particular page

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a parent .sass file where I define the following rule

```
.printableLogo {
    display: none;

    &.hide {
        @media print {
            overflow: hidden;
            display: block !important;
        }
    }
}
```

for a particular page I want to make the display as none.

how to achieve that?

Comment: you can add style to that particular page

Comment: the display is none in your code already. my idea would be to place a class or id on the particular page and write another rule for that special case

Comment: you are using same class name using "!important" :&.hide {
    @media print {
        overflow: hidden;
        display: none !important;
    }
}

Comment: Use an inline rule and apply it to the div.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: Introduce a style attribute directly on the element on that specific page (style="display:none;"). Be aware the important will override this style. So either remove important from you sass or add it to the inline one.

Solution 2: Put an specific class or id on the element on that page that you can then reference in your sass.

Solution 3: Introduce a unique id on the body for each page that you can then reference in your sass to apply styles to elements on specific pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new `.sass` file and link it below the common css file and use for example:

```
display:unset !important;
```

Comment: Note that the `unset` value is not supported by all major browsers though: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-unset-value (spoiler: IE doesn't support it)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do one of the following.

1. **Never** use `!important` in the parent/global CSS file
2. If needed to override that, **write inline CSS or add a CSS tag in the particular page**.
3. **Add another unique class/id for the particular div** and apply styling for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<body class="pagenumber1">

.pagenumber1 .printableLogo {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will also not suggest using display: unset !important;  you can add a id for overriding the CSS if there no way to add inline CSS or id then you can use display: unset !important;

you can also try this in a specific page template

```css
<style>
.selector{
  display:none;
}
<style>
```